# Deleting IOS 9.3.5 on iPad 2?

Tags: ipad

sorry if this has been asked before.

I was told that IOS 10 won't download on iPad if IOS 9.3.5 is already installed. I have checked how to remove it so I can install IOS 10, but when I try follow the instructions given on most sites, I can't because it's not there in the list of storage to delete. Does anyone know why this is, and what to do about it?

Answer (score 2):

You have been misled. If your iPad is capable of running iOS 10 (you don't specify the model) then you should see the update notification for it.

To check, follow these steps on the iPad:

- Open Settings
- Tap on General
- Tap on Software Update
- You will either get a message that it's checking for an update, or you will see a message informing you that you can update to iOS 10.x, or you will see a message stating that your software is up-to-date

Follow the above steps and let me know what you see?

**[EDIT]**

I've just realised you had referenced *iPad 2* in your question title. This generation of iPad **does not support** any version of iOS above iOS 9.3.5. This is why you're not able to update to iOS 10.